# How to read cookie from redirect response header

Tags: javascript, cookies, header, response, returnurl

I am having some authentication module, for authentication it goes on other domain with return url, and after login,  again it redirect back to the original domain.

How can i read the cookies from redirect response header ?

and i am using php and javascript and other domain is using ASP.net

Best Regards,
AFFAN.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The cookies are only communicated between the host that set them and the browser.

The browser only exposes them to JS though `document.cookies` for the host that the HTML document was served from.

Since you are getting a redirect instead of an HTML document, JavaScript will never see them.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer, but now what should i tell them, how we can do Authentication from different Domain and redirect to our domain